# MySQL - select a distinct combination of 2 columns and return the values separately

Tags: mysql

I need to select a distinct combination of columns A and B and return the values of A for all rows where the combination of A, B is not unique.

This is my query to which somehow I want to add the column A to display in the results:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, count(id) as cnt FROM files_imported WHERE file_id = 13 GROUP BY A, B HAVING cnt > 1
```

Query works fine as is, but I need to modify it so I can get the values for A where the above conditions are met.

Answer (score 0):

You can use '[UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html)' to merge two query results (need to point out they need to have the same column data types - this to explain the '' from the second query)
So your query would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A, B, count(id) as cnt FROM files_imported WHERE file_id = 13 GROUP BY A, B HAVING cnt > 1
UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT A, '', count(id) as cnt FROM files_imported WHERE file_id = 13 GROUP BY A, B HAVING cnt = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT distinct A
FROM files_imported
WHERE file_id = 13
GROUP BY A, B
HAVING count(id) > 1;
```